# Send client certificate using XHR

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to open an ssl service with java script.
In order to do so, I need to send my certificate with xmlhttp object.
Can I do it with java script? I could not find how to do it anywhere.

my code looks like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("post","https://[some ip]:[some secured port]",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

However it's not working. On the other hand, when using:
"https://[some ip]:[some secured port]" - directly from my browser - It is telling me to choose a certificate and it's working well.

How can I make it work straight from the java script?
What should be the solution to my situation?

Comment: you might wanna read this extensive talk about a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9542772/575527

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Besides that, the same origin policy would most likely cause problems for you.

Comment: Not possible? So what is possible if I want to send a certificate using ajax / javascript etc.?

Comment: It might work if the browser is set to automatically choose one. But then again, it will only work to the same host:port for security reasons. There are some approaches such as CORS and `XDomainRequest` though which will work in recent browsers.

Comment: What about this link I found:
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/459071-ajax-https

It is telling me it is possible.

Comment: Is there any way to bridge this gap quicky - without too many code changes? For example, a different object to use that passes client certificates? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's one solution you might consider. If you detect that the certificate is absent, you may try to create an iframe with 0 height and width and border: none (basically an invisible iframe), point it to the needed URL and then the browser displays the certificate selection window.

I tested that in Firefox and Edge, both seems to work with that workaround.